# change height of div element to screen-height from controller angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs, scrollbar

I don't know how to resolve this, any help would be awesome.

I have a div element where I am displaying data (div element is on the left side of the screen). I want to add a scrollbar only to this div element. I was able to do this.

```
<div style="float: left; 
            width: 100%;  
            overflow-y: auto; 
            max-height: 500px;">
```

But here's the problem, I am viewing this in different screen resolutions, so far large screens if the data fits in the screen there should be no scrollbar.

Using

```
$window.innerHeight
```

I am getting the screen height. But how do I set this height as the "max-height" value for the div element from the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
<div ng-style="{ 'width' : width, 'max-height' : screenHeight, 'overflow-y': autoVar }"></div>
```

in controller,

```
$scope.width = '100%';
$scope.screenHeight = '700px';
$scope.autoVar = 'auto';
```